# Is it advisable to use Single Table Inheritence over Users table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For a current project of mine, I am trying to first design the database schema for the application. However, I am unable to decide whether or not to use [Single Table Inheritence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) on the User model for my application.

A User can be an: Owner, Resident, or Admin, and since they share same attributes with different functions, I think STI applies here. Am I going in the right direction with this? If not, please suggest better alternatives. Is polymorphic association a fit here? Note that, authentication and access control is intended on Users, as normally would.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct -- STI would be appropriate in this case. And since authentication is intended on Users, it would give you the simpler solution. Also, since they share attributes as well, I would say STI over polymorphic association -- the only thing that differs is the type of the user, which that handles.

Comment: Also, if you mean to use Devise, you will save yourself the headaches associated with having multiple Devise models.  Which means a single login screen, a single set of custom controllers, etc.

Comment: Also, you might consider using a User -> Roles relationship with CanCan, especially if its primarily Roles that differentiate your user base.

Comment: @ipd: i was actually considering using CanCan (great fan of RyanBates), but I don't think STI would be supported there (and was a part reason why I asked this question, in the first place)

Comment: @ipd absolutely, it will make working Devise really easy. You should be able to use CanCan with that though -- you are just defining the roles, the authorization should be simple (but I have not used CanCan yet so I cannot say for sure)

Comment: i can't think of a reason why CanCan would not play nice with STI.  But i'm also not sure you would need STI if you define roles in your User model.  It would depend on how different you wanted to make your user classes, if it was just roles that differentiated them, then you probably wouldn't need STI at all.